# How to animate setValue in Jquery Tools

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-tools

I have this plugin:
[enter link description here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/rangeinput/index.html)
The thing i want to do is this:
When i click on a link, i want to animate the slider. But setValue is not doing any animation, just jump to the specific value:

rangeapi.setValue(200);

I have an idea for the animation, for example, if the slider value is 100, and i want to change it to 200:

rangeapi.setValue(101);
rangeapi.setValue(102);
...
rangeapi.setValue(199);
rangeapi.setValue(200);

But i don't know how to do that.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function SlideValue (initial, count){
    var x = function (){       
        count--;
        initial++;
        rangeapi.setValue(initial);
        if (count > 0) document.window.setTimeout(x, 1000);
    };
    x();
}

SlideValue(100, 5);
```